# How can I use a different separator for interpolation lookups?

Tags: java, configuration, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

I use Apache Commons Configuration to load config files. In the past, the configs `getProperty()` method was overwritten so that a `${encoded 21$%Ds}` within a property value was returned as a decoded value. This should now be improved.

I know that with a colon separated `${encoded:21$%Ds}` I could easily retrieve and decode the value automatically by setting a lookup to the configs interpolator ([1](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html)):

```
ConfigurationInterpolator interpolator = config.getInterpolator();
interpolator.registerLookup("encoded", new DecodeLookup());
```

with `DecodeLookup` looking like

```
public class BogisLookup implements Lookup {
  @Override
  public Object lookup(String varName) {
    String decodedVar = decode(varName);
    return decodedVar;
    }
}
```

Since the version with the space (`${encoded 21$%Ds}`) is already widely adopted I need to adjust the interpolation lookup separator from `":"` to `" "`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Process data through regular expressions:

```
String[] parts = varName.split("\\s+");
```

In this way, an array can be obtained, where data with index 0 is Key and data with index 1 is Value. If the length exceeds 2, an error can be thrown. When the length verification is passed, the data with index 1 can be directly obtained for decoding

Comment: It will not reach the lookup method when using ${encoded 21$%Ds}. Only when using ${encoded:21$%Ds}

Comment: This requires you to modify Lookup to adapt to ${encoded 21 $% Ds}